# GitHub oAuth app authorization with javascript only

Tags: javascript, github, oauth

I've been searching around for a while and I haven't found anything that would really help me.

My question is whether is it possible to make the authorization with pure js without using a server? If yes, then how to do so?

Let's say my callback URL is set to http://localhost:3000/callback - how do I handle the callback? Is this URL even correct? Can I hide sensitive data with this approach?

I know I could use Node.js but let's say I can't for some reason. Just pure client-side JS.

Thanks!

Comment: No pure client side authorization is safe. Maybe giving a code example would help to show what exactly you are trying to achieve

Comment: I haven't written anything yet, it is just a concept.

Comment: You have to understand, that no authorization when done on client side - meaning, all the code is accesible in dev tools in your browser - can be safe/protected. For that reason you need server, that has credentials (name/password) saved in DB or file

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that it isn't the safest approach but I still wanna know if it is possible, research purposes only.

Comment: From what I got so far I would say you are trying to do impossible. But still it's not really clear to me what are you trying to achieve. You write about pure JS with no server solution, but you mention callback URL which indicates a server (even though a local one).

Comment: So this probably answers my (stupid) question. When I set a oAuth app on GitHub I have to specify a callback URL, so it's that. This should be handled by a server and nothing else, is thar correct?

Comment: URL u mentioned is the url of some server. So yes, you need a server. Also when looking on oauth app on github documentation your app, must run on server either local or public.